# simulate marker on stage

Tags: ros, gazebo, multi-robot, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to simulate multi-robot behavior os stageros. I want my robots to be conveyed a message when they reach a marker(anytype fiducial or bar code). player-stage which has support both for markers and fiducials( http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Stage-3.2.1/group__model__camera.html , http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Stage-3.2.1/group__model__fiducial.html).  I guess camera is absent in stageros.

So ar_pose marker won't work(http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose) on stageros. So can i get any other marker to be simulated in stage to achieve the desired task or alternatively can Gazebo simulate multi-robots with camera and markers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38819/simulate-marker-on-stage/) by [iceman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2843/iceman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-07-16**:
@iceman Do you plan to use blobfinder proxy ?

**Comment by [iceman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2843/iceman/) on 2012-07-17**:
I've used it with player/stage before:http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Player-cvs/player/group__playerc__proxy__blobfinder.html ..but, I can't find any support for camera or makers in stageros..i can't find any gazebo code either. have you used multiple robots with cameras in simulation?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-07-19**:
@iceman stageros doesn't support camera, markers or multiple robots - if you plan to work with such, I would suggest that you better stick to Player/Stage or alternatively use the stage executables in ROS (obviously without the ROS nodes - stage is the executable, stageros is the wrapper to ROS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case it is still truly an open question, I have used multiple robots (each with a [camera](http://answers.ros.org/question/43238/using-stageros-and-a-simulated-camera/)) in stage.

The [patch](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4058) is currently still posted on code.ros.org, but the true home for the issue is over on [github](https://github.com/rtv/Stage/issues/34).

I cannot yet speak to use of the blobfinder in ros, but the [cmvision](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cmvision) package seems to provide the same functionality that was present in player/stage. Sadly the package maybe orphaned (based on these [instructions](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Detect_Blobs_using_ROS_Package_cmvision)).

Looks like opencv may be the path forward [tutorial-on-opencv-simpleblobdetector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076889/tutorial-on-opencv-simpleblobdetector).. also check out the question on [answers.ros](http://answers.ros.org/question/42268/cvblob-and-cvblobslib/)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0